# Code that works on my localhost (PHP 5.3.4) is not working on older PHP environment on live server (PHP 5.2.17)

Tags: php

This is my code that is working nice on my localhost:

```
<?php
$list = array();
array_map(function($var){}, $matches_array_1);
foreach ( $matches_array_1 as $value ) {
    $key = $value['team'];

    if (array_key_exists($key, $list)) {
        $list[$key]['team_points'] += $value['team_points'];
        $list[$key]['team_occurrences'] ++;
    } else {
        $list[$key] = $value;
        $list[$key]['team_occurrences'] = 1;
    }
}
usort($list ,function($a, $b){ $a = $a['team_points'] ; $b = $b['team_points'] ; return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 : -1 ) ;});

?>
```

But on the server it throws an error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'**

for this line:

```
array_map(function($var){}, $matches_array_1);
```

**My localhost WAMP PHP version is 5.4.3**

**My server PHP version is 5.2.17**

I would like to change th code so it works on both environments.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't understand why so many hosting providers are still stuck on PHP 5.2. It was declared end of life nearly *two years ago*! It has been unsupported ever since then. It is out of date and **insecure**. If your server is PHP 5.2, you need to upgrade it as a matter of urgency. If you're using a host that won't upgrade from 5.2, then you're using a host that has a dangerously cavalier attitude to their security; if they won't upgrade, you should switch hosts as a matter of urgency.

Comment: Yes, I have talked with them. It seems it will be ok after weekend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anonymous functions are available from PHP 5.3.0. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php